# Align thumbnail

Tags: plugin-list-category-post

I've created my own template yet I can't figure out how to specify CSS attributes to an individual $lcp_display_output option.  In this case I'd like to align the thumbnail to none to allow the excerpt to display to the right of the tn.  How can I accomplish that?

Comment: Are you using the plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts/ or are you using the core function http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the List Category Posts plugin, it uses WordPress' native function to get the thumbnail [get_the_post_thumbnail](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail) which produces:

```
class="attachment-thumbnail wp-post-image"
```

You should assign style to those classes. More info about that [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_post_thumbnail#Styling_Post_Thumbnails).

I'll be adding the thumbnail CSS class as a parameter since get_the_post_thumbnails has that as an optional parameter, so you'll have better customization on a future release.

**UPDATE:** Ok, now I added the functionality to send the CSS class as a parameter for your thumbnail:

**thumbnail_class** - Set a CSS class to the thumbnail and style it.

This is working as of version 0.21 of [List Category Posts](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/list-category-posts).